# What would be a regex for valid xml names?

Tags: xml

```
[a-zA-Z_:]([a-zA-Z0-9_:.])*
```

Would this do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you mean XML *element* names? If so, no, that's too exclusive, there are lots of valid characters that that doesn't cover. More in the spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

```
NameStartChar    ::=    ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] |
                        [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] |
                        [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] |
                        [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] |
                        [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF] 

NameChar         ::=    NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 |
                        [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040] 

Name             ::=    NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

Comment: @Johannes: Good edit, thanks. And here *I'm* the one usually complaining people aren't quoting enough.

Comment: For namespace aware xml parsers the definition is slightly changed to only allow at most one ':', and not at the beginning. See QName on http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames for details.

Comment: And if you think this is complex you should see what it was like *before* they (controversially) backported the XML 1.1 name character model to XML 1.0 Fifth Edition!

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

**.NET also has the method [XmlConvert.VerifyName(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.verifyname.aspx).**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML):

Unicode characters in the following code point ranges are valid in XML 1.0 documents:

- U+0009
- U+000A
- U+000D
- U+0020–U+D7FF
- U+E000–U+FFFD
- U+10000–U+10FFFF

Unicode characters in the following code point ranges are always valid in XML 1.1 documents:

- U+0001–U+0008
- U+000B–U+000C
- U+000E–U+001F
- U+007F–U+0084
- U+0086–U+009F

The preceding code points are contained in the following code point ranges which are only valid in certain contexts in XML 1.1 documents:

- U+0001–U+D7FF
- U+E000–U+FFFD
- U+10000–U+10FFFF

Comment: That simplest case it getting you not very far; I'd consider it harmful, in fact.

Comment: @Johannes: ok I'll agree to that, but the purpose of that simple example was more in response to his initial RegEx expression (I thought it would be helpful to him), before you did such a great job of editing it :)

Answer (score 3):

Background Information:

According to [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp) the rules for tag names in XML are

1. Element names are case-sensitive
2. Element names must start with a letter or underscore
3. Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
4. Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and periods
5. Element names cannot contain spaces

---

Possible Solution:

Let's do it in a couple of steps, using javascript. Please feel free to translate as necessary. Why one complex regex when you can break it down into more readable and maintainable code with multiple regex tests?

```
function isXMLTagName ( tag ) // returns true if meets cond. 1-5 above
{
    var t = !/^[xX][mM][lL].*/.test(tag); // condition 3 
    t = t && /^[a-zA-Z_].*/.test(tag);  // condition 2
    t = t && /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+$/.test(tag); // condition 4
    return t; 
}
```

I have this same problem in a project right now. Hope this works.

Answer (score 3):

> ^(:|[A-Z]|_|[a-z]|[\xC0-\xD6]|[\xD8-\xF6]|[\xF8-\u02FF]|[\u0370-\u037D]|[\u037F-\u1FFF]|[\u200C-\u200D]|[\u2070-\u218F]|[\u2C00-\u2FEF]|[\u3001-\uD7FF]|[\uF900-\uFDCF]|[\uFDF0-\uFFFD])(:|[A-Z]|_|[a-z]|[\xC0-\xD6]|[\xD8-\xF6]|[\xF8-\u02FF]|[\u0370-\u037D]|[\u037F-\u1FFF]|[\u200C-\u200D]|[\u2070-\u218F]|[\u2C00-\u2FEF]|[\u3001-\uD7FF]|[\uF900-\uFDCF]|[\uFDF0-\uFFFD]|-|\\.|[0-9]|\xB7|[\u0300-\u036F]|[\u203F-\u2040])*$

This would match correctly all but **[#xFDF0-#xFFFD]|[#x10000-#xEFFFF]** as it is not possible (as far as I know) to match ASCII characters outside 16bit in regex.

To correct xml names you can use this function:

```php
private static function getValidXMLName($value){
    $validStartNameChar =
        '[A-Z]|_|[a-z]|[\xC0-\xD6]|[\xD8-\xF6]|[\xF8-\x{2FF}]|[\x{370}-\x{37D}]|[\x{37F}-\x{1FFF}]|'.
        '[\x{200C}-\x{200D}]|[\x{2070}-\x{218F}]|[\x{2C00}-\x{2FEF}]|[\x{3001}-\x{D7FF}]|[\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}]|[\x{FDF0}-\x{FFFD}]';
    $validNameChar = $validStartNameChar . '|\-|\.|[0-9]|\xB7|[\x{300}-\x{36F}]|[\x{203F}-\x{2040}]';
    
    $valueClean = preg_replace('/(?!'.$validNameChar.')./u','',$value);
    $firstChar = mb_substr($valueClean, 0, 1);
    if (!(strlen(preg_replace('/(?!'.$validStartNameChar.')./u', '', $firstChar)) > 0)) {
        return '_' . $valueClean;
    }
    
    return $valueClean;
}
```

This will replace any incorrect characters with nothing and if the first character after this is not a valid first character will prepend an underscore

Its not maybe the prettiest or best way but for what I am using it for (building an XML log) it will be fine

Comment: Great! Thanks! Just a small correction - it would be better to use mb_substr() instead of substr() because if the first character is 2 byte Unicode substr() will get only the first byte and therefore incorrectly interprete it as not allowed character.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following basic criteria:

- permitted characters are the standard 26 Latin letters, 10 Arabic numerals, and the underscore,
- the leading character can be only a valid letter or an underscore,
- the name cannot start with "xml" in any case variation

I use the following regex pattern for basic XML element (tag) name validation:

```
/^([_a-z][\w]?|[a-w_yz][\w]{2,}|[_a-z][a-l_n-z\d][\w]+|[_a-z][\w][a-k_m-z\d][\w]*)$/i
```

...which is pretty short compared with most single-string examples I've seen and it works quickly, and very well, *within the confines of the outlined strictures*.

Breakdown:

- the first block validates any string of 1 or 2 characters in length.
- the second block validates any 3+ character string that doesn't start with an "x" (or "X").
- the third block validates any 3+ character string that doesn't have an "m" (or "M") in the 2nd position.
- the fourth block validates any 3+ character string that doesn't have an "l" (or "L") in the 3rd position.
- /i sets the Case-Insensitive flag, to significantly reduce the number of character literals needed within the blocks.

I posted this with the idea that it may help anyone who's looking for a slightly more straight-forward (albeit Anglo-centric) solution for parsing a simplified set of XML element (tag) names.

Comment: IMHO -(hyphen), :(colon) and .(dot) is also a permitted letter but can not be a start letter and \w does not cover it.

Comment: So then just change `[/w]` to `[:/w.-]` in such use-cases...

Answer (score 0):

for Node 10 and newest Chrome

```
/[\p{L}_][\p{L}.\d_-]/u
```

Comment: I guess this one misses an asterix and it needs to match the whole string, so I suggest `^[\p{L}_][\p{L}.\d_-]*$`. N.B. `p{L}` means the unicode letter class and `u` means "match unicode".